# What DPI settings are commonly used by professional programmers?

Tags: visual-studio, development-environment

I'm not professional myself. I'm just curious, what DPI settings are most commonly used by professional programmers for their development machines?

Is there a "standard" that most programmers should follow?

Thanks

Comment: Well done - you've asked a question that's off-topic, subjective/argumentative, _and_ not a real question!

Comment: @Matt Ball: How is that so? Perhaps a bit off topic, but not really. Flag it if you think so.

Comment: We programmers really love standards. That's why we all create our own. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what your question is here ... most OSs scale the application's UI according to the monitor's DPI.

When it comes to designing programs that don't utilize automatic scaling (like games etc.) my colleagues who design the UIs used to work with 72 DPI but have switched to 96 DPI in recent years.

Since I personally use a monitor with about 109 DPI old applications designed for 72 DPI often are almost unusable because of small text and tiny buttons.

Hope this answers your rather unspecific question.